# Accept a varied number of arguments through a lambda expression in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, delegates, lambda

I've gotten  myself in a bit of a tangle.  Take a look at the following:

```
Friend Sub RunEvent(ByVal ObjectUID As Long, ByVal EventUID As Long, ByVal Arguments As GenericEventArgument)
    RunSafeCheck(ObjectUID, EventUID)
    For Each E As CustomEvent In MonitoredEvents(ObjectUID)(EventUID)
            E.EventDelegate.DynamicInvoke(Arguments.ArgList)
    Next
End Sub
```

This particular code bit will run any number of delegates passed to it.  One such delegate passed is a lambda expression:

```
    Public Function ConnectEvent(ByVal E As Long, ByVal lua_delegate As LuaFunction) As CustomEvent
        Return GlobalShare.Game.EventManager.RegisterEvent(UID, E, Sub(args() As Object)
                                                                       lua_delegate.Call(args)
                                                                   End Sub)
    End Function
```

I really need `args` to be a paramarray, however, this isn't allowed in lambda expressions.  The problem is that my first code bit sends different arguments depending on some of the situations involved.  It will properly send the the arguments as long as they equal 1 (currently) and this is a problem.  In many cases, it is necessary for it to send many many many more arguments (or none at all in some instances).

Is there any way to get this lambda expression to except any number of arguments while not making it a special case?

**Just for clarification...**  `RunEvent` goes through an list and invokes each delegate inside it.  `ConnectEvent` adds my lambda function to that list.

Comment: I might be missing something, but what does the first function `RunEvent` have to do with the 2nd part of the code?

Comment: @Magnus :: Thanks for saying something, I believe that I've clarified that up now.